# How to read a bytes object like Python's open?

Tags: python

I am downloading files in a cloud environment whereby I am given the file as a type `bytes`.

The formatting on the bytes file conflicts with my processing and thus I would like the bytes file to conform to the way Python handles this basic function:

```
f = open(r"file.log", "r").readlines()
```

Is there a way that I can massage a `type(bytes)` object to look and behave like the above `f`?

## Edit:

The bytes file is NOT saved to disk. It is stored in memory. It looks like

```
type(downloaded_bytes) # bytes
```

This fails:

```
f = open(downloaded_bytes, "rb").readlines()
```

### Edit 2:

These are not equivalent:

```
f = io.BytesIO(downloaded_bytes).readlines()
f2 = open(r"file.log", "r").readlines()
f == f2  # false
```

Comment: use "rb" to read a file as bytes: `open("file.log", "rb")`

Comment: @Blackgaurd, the OP's data is coming from a `bytes` object that's already in-memory, not from a file. (They've edited to make that even more explicit, but I thought it was clear even in the original version of the question).

Comment: Do you know the encoding of `downloaded_bytes`? Otherwise you can't reliably convert it to text (strings).

Answer (score 2):

This is what [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) is for:

```
import io

f = io.BytesIO(downloaded_bytes).readlines()
```

Alternately, since you're using `'r'` instead of `'rb'` in your file example, one might instead end up with something like:

```
import io

f = io.StringIO(downloaded_bytes.decode('utf-8')).readlines()
```

...presuming that UTF-8 is indeed the correct encoding.

Comment: The files are not equivalent, however.

Comment: Right, a BytesIO is equivalent to opening with `'rb'` instead of just `'r'`. For equivalence to just `'r'` you need to decode the bytes into a `str` and use an `io.StringIO()`.

Comment: @JohnStud, err. Your "edit 2" came after the first edit to this question, which added a StringIO-based alternative. (Also, there's no reason to put edit markers in your question: The history is available for everyone to see, and it's more important to make the question easy-to-read for people who are seeing it for the first time than to make the text include a duplication of publicly-readable metadata for the benefit of people who already saw an older version: More people are going to be seeing the question for the first time in the future than have seen it in the past).

Comment: @JohnStud yes, they are.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, ...they're not equivalent in the code quoted in the question using `BytesIO`, but then, that's why this answer also demonstrates `StringIO` (which the OP seems to be ignoring for some reason).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I understand that